# Any disadvantages to using WebView as opposed to TextView in Android

Tags: android

I am making an app a bit like a dictionary, where a user clicks on a word and get a display of an image and an explanation of that word. I know that WebView allows me to use html formatting but I have read that it takes a lot of memory. Is there any disadvantage to using a WebView in this way or should I use a TextView?
WebView works well on my phone, an HTC Wildfire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView` works fine if you only want to display text -- or only very simple formating.

If you want to display something more advanced, `WebView` will definitely allow you to do more, as it allows one to use Full-HTML.

Of course, this requires more power... but, still, if you are only using one WebView at a time on your screen/activity, it cannot be worse than when using the browser application -- and that one works fine, doesn't it ?